# Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $W=P_3(\mathbb{R})$. If $T$ is a linear transformation that satisfies $T(1,1)=x+x^2$ and $T(3,0)=x-x^3$, what is $T(2,2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know how to find transformations of vectors to vectors and polynomials to polynomials but I am having difficulty finding a "connection" between the polynomials and vectors. This is homework question and any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Well a linear transformation satisfies $T(cx)=cT(x)$. Now if you take your $c=2$ and $\mathbf{x}=(1,1)$, then $T((2,2))=2x+2x^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that 
$$
c_1\cdot (1, 1)+c_2\cdot(3, 0) = (2, 2)\tag{1}
$$
Then applying $T$ to (1) gives
$$
c_1\cdot T(1, 1)+c_2\cdot T(3, 0) = T(2, 2)
$$
so that
$$
c_1\cdot (x+x^2)+c_2\cdot(x-x^3)=T(2, 2)\tag{2}
$$
That is, if we can find $c_1$ and $c_2$ in (1), then (2) gives a formula for $T(2, 2)$.

Can we find such $c_1$ and $c_2$?